# The problem of using templates when using apidoc to create API documents

Tags: api-doc

I use apidoc 0.5 X version of the program, when generating documents, you need to customize some data and generate them with templates
I can modify it in the global template and it can work normally,
But when I add the - t parameter on the command line,When specifying the location of the template, I will
There is a problem

```
yarn run v1.22.17
$ apidoc  --template ./templates/ 
warn: No config files found.
(node:11293) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot find module 'templates/src/webpack.config.js'
Require stack:
```

I only changed the location of the template,
Inside the project, you can use git to save the template
I hope you can solve my problem. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

A solution has been found
This -t requires an absolute path, not a relative path, when specifying the path. This can solve the problem, but it can't solve the problem at all,

```
apidoc  --template /Users/****/****/templates/
```

That's no problem
But I'm depressed
There's no perfect solution to the problem I need